# trim zeros from (substring of) nsString in xpcom

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xpcom, gecko, xulrunner

I'm trying to get trim leading zeros if any from a substring of a string containing alphanumeric such as ABC13, 09889, etc.

Here is the sample code i'm trying. Not sure about what type of string would fit for this purpose, hence using nsString.

```
nsString logicId;
    // this is nice way to assing values to nsString, mozilla way.
    logicId.Assign(NS_ConvertASCIItoUTF16((v)));// v is my value such as ABC786

    if(logicId.Length() > 0)
    {
        nsAString& lastFive = Substring(logicId, 17, 5);
        // lastFive is now a string representing the last 5 characters
        // let's trim leading zeros.
            lastFive.Trim("0", true, false);
        plugin->mId.Assign(lastFive);
    }
```

Since a substring is just a const pointer, you can't do a trim on it. So how do get a substring and still trim on it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

i managed to do it as :

```
nsString logicId;

logicId.Assign(NS_ConvertASCIItoUTF16((v)));

        /* mozilla style */
        if(logicId.Length() > 0)
        {

            nsString lastFive(Substring(logicId, 17, 5));
            //and then trim that
            lastFive.Trim("0", true, false);

            plugin->mId.Assign(lastFive);
            //printf("%s\n", NS_ConvertUTF16toUTF8(lastFive).get());

        }
```

Comment: Thanks for charing! this is c++ huh?

Comment: its c++ inside a xpcom component. In a world of xulrunner. xulrunner is not recommended anymore, you should use firefox now when writing components. but yes, you can write components in both c++ and js in firefox.

Comment: Very nice, is your c++ addon open source? Ii would really love to see how this is all done. :)

Comment: hi, nopes its not my add-on. but you can find tutorial on net about writing c++ addons in firefox. i don't know if devs still do that. there's new things called jpm that you can use to add node modules in your add-ons. i think that gives more flexibility as you can write modules in js/c++ and call it from jpm.

Comment: Can you please link me to one of these tutorials. I want to test out some code in C before implementing in jsctypes.

Comment: first try writing simple c++ code and call them from node modules as in this [c++ node module](http://www.benfarrell.com/2013/01/03/c-and-node-js-an-unholy-combination-but-oh-so-right/). Then, if your module works fine..let's say a simple hello world, then try calling it from [firefox jpm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Getting_Started_%28jpm%29)

Comment: Wouldn't that C++ execute outside of the scope of firefox though? I need to execute code within the context, specifically I need to do `XChangeProperty` on the most recent window used i would get the most recent handle from nativeHandle: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Finding_Window_Handles#OS_Specific_Examples_Using_nsIBaseWindow_-%3E_nativeHandle from nsIBaseWindow, do you have any C++ firefox addon you can share? :) like raw code and show me how to compile it please? :)

Comment: please ask this in a separate thread on SO or firefox ml. i'm sure expert on firefox could point you to the right direction. also, when you ask your question, explain it in detail as to what you are doing and trying to achieve with your code.